# Changing Background and Foreground with linked css in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have looked literally everywhere. The goal is to
Use the classes in the stylesheet to set color and background
For example, class selector colorA will set the text color to color ‘A’
Change the color of the text by changing the class of the div with id foreground
Change the background color by changing the class of the div with id background.

I was able to change it by manually entering the color, but when I try to change it by getting className it fails.
Here is my code Ive tried several different things with no luck, please help:

**JavaScript:**

```
function changeBG(col) {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0];
  x.backgroundColor = (col);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>

<div class="holder">
<div id="background" class="backgroundC">
    <div id="foreground" class="colorE">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum </p>

</div>
</div>
</div>

 <div class="holder">
<table>
 Foreground <INPUT type="button" value="A" class = "colorA" name="button3"        onClick= "document.fgColor= 'colorA'">
     <INPUT type="button" value="A" class = "colorB" name="button3" onClick="document.fgColor='.colorB'">

    Background <INPUT type="button" value="B" class = "backgroundA" name="button3" onClick="document.bgColor = '.backgroundA'">
     <INPUT type="button" value="B" class = "backgroundB" name="button3" onClick= changeBG(document.getElementsByClassName("backgroundB"))>
</table>
</div>
```

**CSS Stylesheet:**

```
.colorA {
  color: #4581cf;
}

.colorB {
  color:  #B7E2FF;
}

.backgroundA {
  background-color: #4581cf;
}

.backgroundB {
  background-color:  #B7E2FF;
}
```

Comment: Use .className to change class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changeBG's first parameter is wrong.

***in w3c getElementsByClassName method definition***

The getElementsByClassName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object

**in html code, click event binding**
`onClick= changeBG(document.getElementsByClassName("backgroundB"))`

**in js, click event handler**
`x.backgroundColor=col;`

col object is a collection of elements have class attribute containing 'backgroundB'.
backgroundColor is a element property, set with color value. ex) #f3f3f3

You can fix it like this.

```
x.className = "background" + col[0].value; //col[0] is the input element classfied 'backgroudB'. col[0].value equals 'B'
```

The className property sets or returns the class name of an element.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough you are the best, ive been pounding away at this all week and finally got it!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

Make sure you are passing correct class nam

```
function changeBG(col) {
      var x = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0];
      x.className=col;
     }
```

Comment: Im sorry I am not understanding? "col" is the classname that i get from document.getElementsByClassName("backgroundB")

Comment: What you were trying to assign class name passed through function to the "backgroundColor"

Comment: Insread use className property to set class name of an element. If you want to using backgroundColor you need pass color code instead of class name

Comment: Thank you for the help I am trying, but still not getting anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery.
Create a new form and then copy this code and paste it, you will notice how specific div in specific class color can be changed easily.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>The Selecter Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".big, #div3").css("background-color", "yellow");
   });
 </script>
</head>


 <body>
  <div class="big" id="div1">
      <p>This is first division of the DOM.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="medium" id="div2">
      <p>This is second division of the DOM.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small" id="div3">
      <p>This is third division of the DOM</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am new to html and javascript we are not on jquery yet. This looks like it would work I just dont know how to translate it to html

Comment: Create a new page and then copy my answer and paste it in created page, then you will figure out how to change background color for any elements within any class